# Error when using `intitle` to display chapter titles with `biblatex-nature`

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex-nature` to format the bibliography for my thesis, and all's going well so far except that I want it to display chapter titles for `@incollection` references, which it doesn't do by default. I found suggestions elsewhere that adding the option `intitle` to the biblatex package call could make it do this, but when I try to do this I get a `! Package keyval Error: intitle undefined.` error.

Could anyone suggest either what's going wrong here, or an alternative way to include the chapter titles in my references?

Here are my MWE files:

```
@collection{hsu2015pathogen,
  title={Pathogen-Host Interactions: Antigenic Variation V. Somatic Adaptations},
  author={Hsu, Ellen and Du Pasquier, Louis},
  volume={57},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@incollection{jack2015evolution,
    series = {Results and {Problems} in {Cell} {Differentiation}},
    title = {Evolution of {Immunity} and {Pathogens}},
    indextitle = {Evolution of {Immunity} and {Pathogens}},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-20819-0_1},
    urldate = {2019-02-27},
    booktitle = {Pathogen-{Host} {Interactions}: {Antigenic} {Variation} v. {Somatic} {Adaptations}},
    publisher = {Springer},
    author = {Jack, Robert S.},
    editor = {Hsu, Ellen and Du Pasquier, Louis},
    year = {2015},
    doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-20819-0_1},
    pages = {1--20}
}
```

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[backend=biber, citestyle=numeric-comp, style=nature,
  sorting=none, natbib=true, maxnames=3, minnames=1, url=false,
  giveninits=true, sortcites=true, date=year,
  doi=false,isbn=false,intitle=false]{biblatex}

\bibliography{mwe}

\begin{document}
\parencite{jack2015evolution} is a chapter in \parencite{hsu2015pathogen}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={References}]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `intitle` was added in `biblatex-nature` v1.2i/v1.3 (2016-10-23). The MWE works fine on my fully updated system with `biblatex` 3.12, Biber 2.12 and `biblatex-nature` v1.3c. If you get an error that must be because your version of `biblatex-nature` is too old. If possible update your entire TeX distribution.

If that is not possible because you are using a work computer with restricted rights or Overleaf, the safest way is to rewrite the driver analogous to https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-nature/commit/0a58f60bb385e8f8c383d156434470649840dc99

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[backend=biber, style=nature,
  maxnames=3, minnames=1, url=false,
  giveninits=true, sortcites=true, date=year,
  doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex}

\providetoggle{bbx:intitle}
\toggletrue{bbx:intitle}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:intitle}
    {%
      \usebibmacro{title}%
      \newblock
    }
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \setunit*{\newunitpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:intitle}
    {%
      \usebibmacro{title}%
      \newblock
    }
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{hsu2015pathogen,
  title={Pathogen-Host Interactions: Antigenic Variation V. Somatic Adaptations},
  author={Hsu, Ellen and Du Pasquier, Louis},
  volume={57},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@incollection{jack2015evolution,
    series = {Results and {Problems} in {Cell} {Differentiation}},
    title = {Evolution of {Immunity} and {Pathogens}},
    indextitle = {Evolution of {Immunity} and {Pathogens}},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-20819-0_1},
    urldate = {2019-02-27},
    booktitle = {Pathogen-{Host} {Interactions}: {Antigenic} {Variation} v. {Somatic} {Adaptations}},
    publisher = {Springer},
    author = {Jack, Robert S.},
    editor = {Hsu, Ellen and Du Pasquier, Louis},
    year = {2015},
    doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-20819-0_1},
    pages = {1--20}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{jack2015evolution} is a chapter in \parencite{hsu2015pathogen}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, but possibly less safe you can get the current version of `biblatex-nature` from CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nature) and drop `nature.bbx` and `nature.cbx` next to your `.tex` file. This could cause version conflicts, but would mean that you would essentially have an updated version of `biblatex-nature` if it works.

BTW: `@collection`s usually don't have an author and `@incollection`s can benefit from `crossref`, so I would make the entries look like

```
@collection{hsu2015pathogen,
  title     = {Pathogen-Host Interactions: Antigenic Variation v. Somatic Adaptations},
  editor    = {Hsu, Ellen and Du Pasquier, Louis},
  series    = {Results and Problems in Cell Differentiation},
  number    = {57},
  year      = {2015},
  publisher = {Springer},
}
@incollection{jack2015evolution,
  title      = {Evolution of Immunity and Pathogens},
  author     = {Jack, Robert S.},
  doi        = {10.1007/978-3-319-20819-0_1},
  pages      = {1--20},
  crossref   = {hsu2015pathogen},
}
```

Unfortunately, the output was not quite as I hoped, but I'm not sure if that is what Nature wants or a bug in the style. If you could double-check the output against Nature guidelines and report this as a bug at https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-nature if it does not look right, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, yes, it was a problem with the package version. I was using the latest version downloaded from `apt` but this turned out to be from 2015 (!). I downloaded and installed the latest texlive distribution and updated the references as you suggested and it all seems to work now. Many thanks!

Comment: Regarding the appearance of the citation, the only thing that seems potentially off is that the chapter title is given in italics like a book title. I wasn't able to find clear guidance from Nature about this, but it seems fine for my purposes.